# Shapeless: map a tuple with some options to options

Tags: scala, shapeless

Having

```
(Some(1), 2, Some(3))
```

I expect to get

```
(Some(1), Some(2), Some(3))
```

With shapeless is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes shapeless can do a lot!

```
  import shapeless._
  import syntax.std.tuple._

  trait basicOption extends Poly1 {
    implicit def default[T] = at[T](t => Some(t))
  }

  object fullOption extends basicOption {
    implicit def caseSome[T] = at[Some[T]](s => s)
    implicit def caseNone = at[None.type](s => s)
  }

  println((Some(1),2,Some(3)).map(fullOption)) // (Some(1),Some(2),Some(3))
  println((Some(1),2,None).map(fullOption)) // (Some(1), Some(2), None)
```

For more examples you can check their [github repo](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/shapeless/tuples.scala)

This is for Shapeless 2.0 and up, if you are using something older you can still do it but instead of calling `map` on the tuple directly you would have to go through a `HList`.

Comment: Good answer and you beat me (and @travisbrown) to it :-)

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is,

```
scala> import shapeless._, syntax.std.tuple._
import shapeless._
import syntax.std.tuple._

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object opt extends opt0 {
  implicit def optId[T <: Option[_]] = at[T](identity)
}
trait opt0 extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[T] = at[T](Option(_))
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object opt
defined trait opt0

scala> (Some(1), 2, Some(3)) map opt
res0: (Some[Int], Option[Int], Some[Int]) = (Some(1),Some(2),Some(3))
```

You'll notice that the `Some[Int]`'s at the first and last position have been preserved whereas the lifted middle element is typed as `Option[Int]`. I've worked on the assumption that what you actually intended was something like this,

```
scala> (Option(1), 2, Option(3)) map opt
res1: (Option[Int], Option[Int], Option[Int]) = (Some(1),Some(2),Some(3))
```

Comment: ah +1 for `T <: Option[_]` much prettier than my ugly solution :-)